# How to make sidebar menu respond to URLs with parameters?

Tags: userfrosting

I define a URL in Slim such as:

```
$app->get('/dashboard/items?', ....
```

I then add a link to it in sidebar.twig, and sure enough, it becomes of class "active" once the link is visited.

However, if the URL contains parameters, the link no longer becomes "active".

> e.g. /dashboard/items?page=3

I want the menu to recognize that we are still on the same page, and be highlighted as active. Best way to fix that?

Thank you

[UserFrosting 0.3.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserFrosting determines which menu item to highlight by [trying to match the current page URL against the URLs in the sidebar menu](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/public/js/sb-admin-2.js#L31-L33).

By default, it is configured to compare the entire URL, before any `#` hashes.  To have it disregard your query parameters as well, try having it split the current URL on both `#` AND `?`:

```
var url_head = url.href.split(/[#\?]+/, 1)[0];
return this.href == url_head;
```